# Connect two computers to same monitors and keyboard

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, desktop, docking-station

I have a desktop and a laptop computers. Currently the desktop computer is connected to two monitors 2560x1440, keyboard and a mouse.

I would like to be able to connect my laptop to those same devices when I'm at home. Ideally through a docking station, but any solution will do.
"KVM Docking Station for Two Laptops" is USB 3 based and only support one 2560x1440 monitor at a time.

My laptop has thunderbolt 3 (USB Type C) and my desktop has the USB 3.1/Type C connectors (I suppose they are same).

Edit:
Monitors have DisplayPort++, HDMI and DVI input

Thank you

Comment: do the monitors have more than one input?What inputs are they?

Comment: Answer edited with monitor inputs

Comment: Would using one input type per  device and switching between them work for you?

Comment: If possible, I would like to be able to keep them both plugged to all devices and switch between them. Something like "KVM Docking Station for Two Laptops" but with better bandwidth obviously, supporting two 2550x1440 monitors.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar setup for desktops at my last workplace (and I sort of do this for my home setup) - they quite simply they had a suitable KVM for one monitor and the keyboard and mouse and switched the secondary monitor manually at the monitor. HDMI and DP should both support 1440p, and the KVM should handle a good chunk of the complexity

Answer (score 0):

Though it might not suit your needs you can use synergy which will connect your desktop and laptop through LAN and enables you to control your laptop and desktop with one mouse and keyboard

Answer (score 0):

First you need a KVM for the switching.  Sounds like 2 hosts with dual display.  There's plenty out there, I link to Startech only as a happy customer of them in the past.
https://www.startech.com/en-us/server-management/kvm-switches?page=1&sort=relevance&filter_kvmports=2&filter_kvmdual=2

The laptop will need a dock, dual display which will add to the cost, to separate out the video from the USB.  Another set of examples, not a product endorsement.
https://www.startech.com/en-us/cards-adapters/laptop-docking-stations?page=1&sort=price-low&filter_bustype=thunderbolt%203&filter_docknumdisplays=2

There are software KVM solutions, some better than others, none as good as a hardware KVM.  They cost some money but then so do the good software KVM packages.  A hardware KVM requires no installed software, and any software included may or may not improve the experience.  There's also mixing a hardware KVM with a software KVM for some neat effects and capability.

I'm a fan of having a hardware KVM.  I recommend getting one highly.